# C#　linq query rank by two conditions

Tags: c#, linq

use C# linq query,
I want to get date ranked by id and updatetime.
id: Contained in a list 'idList'
updatetime:type of datatime

example data:

query:

```css
.onecenter{text-align:center;width:150px;}
```

```html
<table  border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr >
        <td class='onecenter'>id</td>
        <td class='onecenter'>updatetime</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td class='onecenter'>1</td>
        <td class='onecenter'>2016-02-16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td class='onecenter'>2</td>
        <td class='onecenter'> 2016-02-14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td  class='onecenter'>3</td>
        <td  class='onecenter'>2016-02-15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='onecenter'>4</td>
        <td  class='onecenter'>2016-02-17</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

idList:

```
2,3
```

result should be:

```css
    .onecenter{text-align:center;width:150px;}
```

```html
    <table  border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        
        <tr >
            <td class='onecenter'>id</td>
            <td class='onecenter'>updatetime</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
            <td  class='onecenter'>3</td>
            <td  class='onecenter'>2016-02-15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td class='onecenter'>2</td>
            <td class='onecenter'> 2016-02-14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='onecenter'>4</td>
            <td  class='onecenter'>2016-02-17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td class='onecenter'>1</td>
            <td class='onecenter'>2016-02-16</td>
        </tr>
        
       
    </table>
```

how can I get the result by linq query.

I tried:

```
var data1 = query.Where(m => idList.Contains(m.ID)).OrderByDescending(x => x.updatetime);
var data2 = query.Where(m => !idList.Contains(m.ID)).OrderByDescending(x => x.updatetime);
var date = data1.Concat(data2).ToList();
```

and :

```
var data = query.GroupBy(m => idList.Contains(m.ID)).OrderByDescending(x => x.updatetime);
```

but it didnot get the right result.

Comment: have you tried `query.Where(m => idList.Contains(m.ID)).OrderBy(c => c.ID).ThenBy(c => c.updatetime)` ?

Comment: @HariPrasad  `query.Where(m => idList.Contains(m.ID)).OrderBy(c => c.ID).ThenBy(c => c.updatetime)`  this can only get id 2 and 3

Comment: I dont see any problem  with your first query....it should work

Comment: @gdreamlend `Except` keyword may turn to be helpful

Comment: @gdreamlend It will help if you post complete code because I think your first query should work and you may be missing something else

Comment: @gdreamlend agree with Viru, perhaps you can show us your more complete code?

Comment: @Viru  very thank you, there are many codes ahead this but i think show it complete may complicate this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with this query:

```
var result = query.OrderByDescending(q => idList.Contains(q.ID) ? 1 : 0)
                  .ThenByDescending(q => q.updatetime);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
var data1 = query.Where(x => idList.Contains(x.ID)).OrderByDescending(y => y.UpdateTime);
var data2 = query.Except(data1).OrderByDescending(y => y.UpdateTime);
var data = data1.Concat(data2).ToList();
```

Use `Except` for the second one to remove whatever you already have in `data1` then you should be able to get this:

```
[2016-02-17 06:22:04.167 UTC] 3 2/15/2016 12:00:00 AM
[2016-02-17 06:22:04.169 UTC] 2 2/14/2016 12:00:00 AM
[2016-02-17 06:22:04.170 UTC] 4 2/17/2016 12:00:00 AM
[2016-02-17 06:22:04.170 UTC] 1 2/16/2016 12:00:00 AM
```

**Edit:**

In case your data is a lot, you may consider of leaving the items as `IEnumerable` till you need to process it instead of changing it to `List`. This may save up some time:

```
var data1 = query.Where(x => idList.Contains(x.ID)).OrderByDescending(y => y.UpdateTime);
var data2 = query.Except(data1).OrderByDescending(y => y.UpdateTime);
var data = data1.Concat(data2); //don't change to List here

foreach(var dat in data){ //use it by fetching it one by one like this
}
```

Comment: Much better to use Except...but still a question remains why did not first query which OP posted did not work

Comment: @Viru yes, it is pretty strange now that I think about it... What OP does seem to be correct too

Comment: My guess is OP is overlooking something in his code and has posted correct code while asking question...

Comment: used first quert I got "Timeout Error" at the line  `var data = data1.Concat(data2).ToList();`

Comment: @gdreamlend how many data do you have? Seems like you execute it for very long time?

Comment: about 60,000, yeah it takes long time than I think

Comment: @gdreamlend in that case, I suggest you to remove the `ToList()` to speed up the process. Leave it as `IEnumerable` till you need to process it.

Comment: It may because I have other linq operations ahead

Comment: If  remove the ToList() , then Concat() will not work well

Comment: @gdreamlend "If remove the ToList() , then Concat() will not work well" what do you mean? `Concat` is from `Linq` I think, not from `List`